# Listbox with datasource and move feature

Tags: vb.net

I have simply listbox binded to Datasource with display and valuemember defined. However now i need to give user possibility to sort items of that items (up/down) is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListBox follows order of rows in DataSource. So, you have to manipulate rows in DataSource.

For a start, I usually put a DataTable in between the DataSource DataSet and the GUI object:

```
Dim dtMyTable1 as New Datatable

' Load your data from database into dtMyTable 
dtMyTable1 = ds.tables(0)    ' data from your dabase...

' do any re-ordering or data manipulation here... I.e.:
Dim dr1 as DataRow = dtMyTable1.rows(5)
Dim dr2 as DataRow = dtMyTable1.rows(6)
dtMyTable1.Rows.RemoveAt(5)
dtMyTable1.Rows.InsertAt(dr2,5)
dtMyTable1.Rows.RemoveAt(6)
dtMyTable1.Rows.InsertAt(dr1,6)

' assign Datatable to ListBox
Me.ListBox1.datasource = dtMyTable1
```